# Samsung S5 emails not loading

Tags: email

Up until about a week ago my emails were loading fine.  Now it seems like they stopped and only load a few at a time.  Supposed to refresh every 15 minutes but sometimes goes all day before any come in.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?